# Mod rewrite completely rewrite url (ignore all parameters)/partially include parameter name

Tags: php, mysql, mod-rewrite

I'm new to this kind of thing so I apologize  if my question isn't very clear.
My URL look like this

`example.com/language/index?page=detail&idcontact=77`

I want to  rewrite it into this

`example.com/language/contact`

I want  'contact' without id infront of it and ignore everything else

Thank you in advance

Comment: I think you ment it to have it other way: from /contact to /index?page=detail&idcontact=77 or?

Comment: I want to shorten it to make it seo / user friendly.

Comment: So the value of the idcontact parameter is always 77 (and page always detail)?

Comment: 1.both page and idcontact are dynamic 2.idcontact has other value but i only want 77 as the link appear on my navigation bar as "contact us", I have no use for id contact with other values.

Answer (score 0):

URL rewriting isn't working as you might think. If you want to redirect from one URL to another because of SEO, you can do it this way in your .htaccess file:

```
Redirect 301 /language/index?page=detail&idcontact=77 http://example.com/language/contact
```

Be carefull about using codes, `301` means permament redirect. If it's just temporary, use `302`.

If you want to work with URL rewriting, than it's working the other way. In your code you have to use nice URL `example.com/language/contact` and in Your .htaccess you have to rewrite nice URL to ugly URL so your php knows what to do. This isn't the best solution, it's just to show how to do it:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule   ^/language/contact /language/index?page=detail&idcontact=77
```

If you want to make it really work your nice URL could use parameters so your php knows what's in parameter page and idcontact. You can do it this way:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule   ^/language/page-([a-zA-Z]+)/idcontact-([0-9]+) /language/index?page=$1&idcontact=$2
```

This way, you can redirect to any page and parameter page is accepting only letters and idcontact is accepting only numbers.

Comment: Thanks for answering but Rewrite Engine on
RewriteRule   ^/language/contact /language/index?page=detail&idcontact=77 didn't work. I tried that before.  parameter name 'idcontact' has others parameters value but I don't  want them I want that particular address to display on user browser as simply 'contact' since it's one of my main pages. Any suggestion?

Comment: As I wrote above, you need to point to 'contact' page, not to /language/contact /language/index?page=detail&idcontact=77  You are doing it opposite way.

Comment: Huh? I'm doing exactly what you said be below your" This isn't the best solution, it's just to show how to do it:" answer.

Comment: All right. Now when you open page example.com/language/contact do you have correct site there?

Comment: No,I got 404 page not found